# Catch errors in vim/ruby

Tags: ruby, vim

I'm writing a vim plugin using the ruby interface.

When I execute `VIM::command(...)`, how can I detect if vim raised an error during execution of this command, so that I can skip further commands and also present a better message to the user?

Comment: I don't know much about ruby. but if ruby has `try...catch..` (like) exception handling, you can catch the exception in ruby. and you can set vim variable (flag/returnCode) in ruby right? on  Vim side, you can check the variable to decide if you want to "throw" or "echo"..

Comment: Fair enough, but how do I catch command errors in vim?

Comment: vim has `try...catch..` too. `:h :try` and `:h :catch`

Comment: @Kent he is trying to access a Vim error from the Ruby wrapper.

Comment: @p11y I don't have experience with vim's ruby wrapper, that's why I posted as comment. I thought it could (maybe) done by wrapping vim code in try-catch reading the vim built-in variable `v:exception` ?

Comment: @Kent me neither, but I can't imagine that the wrapper actually monitors exceptions inside Vim and re-throws them inside Ruby.

Comment: @p11y in vim's catch, we could set some variable, and later in ruby, we check that variable. we can at least do so if there is no existing mechanism. right? the `v:exception` is just the concrete exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim's global variable `v:errmsg` will give you the last error. If you want to check whether an error occured, you can first set it to an empty string and then check for it:

```
let v:errmsg = ""

" issue your command

if v:errmsg != ""
  " handle the error
endif;
```

I'll leave it up to you to transfer this to the Ruby API. Also see `:h v:errmsg` from inside Vim. Other useful global variables may be:

- `v:exception`
- `v:throwpoint`

**Edit** – this should work (caution: some magic involved):

```
module VIM
  class Error < StandardError; end

  class << self
    def command_with_error *args
      command('let v:errmsg=""')
      command(*args)
      msg = evaluate('v:errmsg')
      raise ::VIM::Error, msg unless msg.empty?
    end
  end
end


# Usage
# use sil[ent]! or the error will bubble up to Vim

begin
  VIM::command_with_error('sil! foobar') 
rescue VIM::Error => e
  puts 'Rescued from: ' + e.message;
end


# Output

Rescued from: E492: Not an editor command: sil! foobar
```

Comment: note that `v:errmsg` is  not read-only variable. which means it could be set in custom codes

Comment: I found that `v:exception` works for what I need (catching `E37` from `:edit`). Thanks to you and Kent!

Comment: (I may write up the full Ruby recipe later.)

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka played around a bit with the VIM module in Ruby and shared my results in the answer.